# con closedxml ¿como puedo procesar 2 bloques de datos distintos que estan en la misma hoja de datos?

Tags: c#, .net

Tengo una hoja de datos con 2 bloques distintos de datos y necesito procesarlos de forma distinta. ¿como podría procesarlos con closedxml y c#?

de antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Y que fue lo que intentaste???

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.